# python Firebase Cloud Storage - upload file without saving it locally

Tags: python, zip, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I want to upload zip file to Firebase Cloud Storage, but I want to avoid saving it locally. Instead, I want to store it in memory (using `BytesIO`), and then upload it directly.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically this should be possible to write from `BytesIO` to storage without writing the file  locally.

There is a method in `Blob` class called `upload_from_string` ([reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)). The method accepts `bytes` and it's possible to add content type as well. Ex. I was able to run something like that:

```
    # create simplest BytesIO object
    b = io.BytesIO(b'hello')
    # create storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    # create test bucket
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("vittoh-test-bytesio")
    # create test blob
    blob = bucket.blob("vitooh-test-blob")
    # upload with type zip
    blob.upload_from_string(b.read(),content_type='application/zip')
```

This created object with content_type "application/zip" in my testing bucket. I don't know how do you want to create this zip file in `BytesIO`, but after that it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```py
zip_stream.seek(0)
blob.upload_from_file(zip_stream)
```

Here is the example. Zipping two csv files generated from Dataframe and upload it to the storage.

```py
import zipfile
import io

files = [("test1.csv", df1.to_csv()), ("test2.csv", df2.to_csv())]

zip_stream = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_stream, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as new_zip:
    for f in files:
        new_zip.writestr(f[0], f[1])

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
blob = bucket.blob(ZIPFILE_NAME_ON_STORAGE)
zip_stream.seek(0)
blob.upload_from_file(zip_stream)
```